# Can I add Png Image as an option to Create New Object Type in Excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016, office365, image-processing

I want to insert several pictures as Objects in Excel 365. These pictures are scans of construction plans that serve as references to some calculations in the file. File readers need to be able to open the plan, zoom in, and check the values used in my calculations.

The Excel default image application is Paint which inserts pictures as .bmp files. The issue is that Bitmap images are very heavy (about 5Mb each) and quickly increase the size of my file to the point where the file cannot be emailed. I would like to be able to introduce the pictures as PNG files that are much smaller in size. The screenshot below shows that the only current option is Bitmap Image.

Does anybody know how to add Png Image to Create New Object options?

[image]

Comment: You can use Create from File option.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going to the "Create New" tab when inserting a new object, go to "Create from File", browse for your PNG file, and that's it!

[image]

Then you've got your PNG Object in your spreadsheet:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! It looks like this does the job. The only issue I have is that it adds 1 extra step in the process, by having to first save my screenshot. The Create New option allows for a straight copy-paste. Normally, 1 extra step would not bother me that much, but the job I have to do involves hundreds of images to be embedded into Excel.